# Strange ROS install behaviour

Tags: arm, debian, ros

So I recently got back into ROS for a project I'm working on, and for that I installed the latest ROS noetic on a raspberry pi 2.
After adding the package list and gpg keys as shown in the tutorial, I tried to install ROS through

`sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop`

Didnt worked, trowing an Unable to locate this package. So I tried a simple `sudo apt-cache search ros-` and I saw some packages but without the **noetic** part, like `ros-desktop` instead of `ros-noetic-desktop`.

So I decided to install it from source and now I'm kinda stuck, trying to install `freenect_stack` with no other choice than to install the whole dependency tree by hand which is a litle annoying considering that I might be facin the same problem more than once in the future ...

Here is the tutorial I followed for the complitation : https://varhowto.com/install-ros-noetic-raspberry-pi-4/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the architechure might been not compatible. I reinstalled it on a fresh ubuntu server on a RPI 3 and it worked just fine.

Hope it helps :)